# SetState doesn't change the source in a video component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I want to have one video play after another video after one second automatically in react, I'm using state and setState to change the source of the video but it doesn't change the video. I'm at a loss.

```
import idle from './video/idle.mp4'
import intro from './video/Intro.mp4'

constructor(){
  super()
  this.state= {
    vid: intro
  }
  
}

componentDidMount(){
 setTimeout (()=> {this.setState ({
    vid: idle
  }
  )}, 1000) ;
 
}

render() {
    return (
   

<div class="grid-container">

    
  <div class="grid-item item2">
<video autoPlay={true} loop muted style={{width:"330px", height:"780px", paddingLeft:"10px", paddingTop:"220px"}}>
    <source src={this.state.vid} type="video/mp4"/></video>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all,** make sure you **import your videos outside your component.**

**Secondly**, are you sure you can **import these .mp4 files this way?** Wouldn't it be better to call them **directly by a relative path?**

At least you could store two paths rather in string and assign these strings to your state

For example :

```
constructor(){
  super()

  this.idlePath = "/assets/videos/idle.mp4";
  this.introPath = "/assets/videos/intro.mp4";
  this.state= {
    vid: ""
  }
  
}
```

And then assign this.state.vid inside a **componentDidMount** method first then when the timeout is over you set the *vid* state to the *introPath*

Comment: It also didn't show any video after implementing this. I can import mp4 files this way because when I just put them it does play.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with functional component:

```js
import {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";

const Component = () => {
  const [ vidName, setVidName ] = useState("Intro");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout (() => {
      setVidName("idle");
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <video
      autoPlay
      loop
      muted
      style={{
        width: "330px",
        height: "780px",
        paddingLeft: "10px",
        paddingTop: "220px"
      }}
    >
      <source
        src={`./video/${vidName}.mp4`}
        type="video/mp4"
      />
    </video>
  );
};
```

Class component:

```js
import React from "react";

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { vidName: "intro" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout (() => {
      this.setState ({ vidName: "idle" });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <video
        autoPlay
        loop
        muted
        style={{
          width: "330px",
          height: "780px",
          paddingLeft: "10px",
          paddingTop: "220px"
        }}
      >
        <source
          src={`./video/${this.state.vidName}.mp4`}
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing plays when I try this.

Comment: You might then have to serve your videos in a slightly different way. Move them under the public folder, something like: `my-app/public/videos/`. Then update the `<source src>` to have path `{\`/videos/${vidName}.mp4\`}`

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the video component updates when the video source URL changes, you can add a `key` prop to the `<video>` component. The `key` prop helps React identify when a component should be updated. Here's the updated code with the `key` prop included:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import idle from './video/idle.mp4';
import intro from './video/Intro.mp4';

class VideoPlayer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      vid: intro,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        vid: idle,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="grid-item item2">
          <video autoPlay loop muted style={{ width: "330px", height: "780px", paddingLeft: "10px", paddingTop: "220px" }} key={this.state.vid}>
            <source src={this.state.vid} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

In this code, the `key` prop is added to the `<video>` component and set to `this.state.vid`. By using the `vid` state value as the `key`, React will recognize the change in the video source URL and update the component accordingly.

Including the `key` prop ensures that React performs the necessary updates when the video source changes, allowing the video player to play the next video after a second.

Please note that the `key` prop should be unique for each video source URL to ensure accurate updates.

Note: have formate answer the with chatgpt